# how to get last inserted value when multiple users enter details in form doing in php and oracle

Tags: php, oracle

i am  trying to insert user data and show that particular details in form who is last inserted :

```
$name=$_POST['name'];
$email_id=$_POST['email_id'];
$number=$_POST['number'];
$remarks=$_POST['remarks'];
$req_name=$_POST['req_name'];
date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Kolkata');
$date=date("d-m-Y");

$insert_data="INSERT INTO FEEDBACK(id, name, email, mobile_num, remarks,req_date) VALUES(FEEDBACK_sequence.nextval,:p_name, :p_email, :p_number, :p_remarks,:p_date)";
oci_bind_by_name($stid, ":p_name", $name);
oci_bind_by_name($stid, ":p_email", $email_id);
oci_bind_by_name($stid, ":p_number", $number);
oci_bind_by_name($stid, ":p_remarks", $remarks);
oci_bind_by_name($stid, ":p_date", $date);
oci_execute($stid) or die(oci_error());
```

in the same page, here i am inserting in user details with auto increment using sequence created and now i want to get last inserted user details in form to show,
like this i am showing the last inserted details, but i want to get details through sequence number using where condition in select query, how can i get last inserted record.

```
$stid = oci_parse($conn, 'select * from FEEDBACK');
$r = oci_execute($stid) or die(oci_error());

while ($row=oci_fetch_array($stid)) {
echo "<tr>\n";
echo "<td><input type='hidden' value='' name='id'>".$row['ID']."</td>";
    echo "<td><input type='text' value='' name='name'>".$row['NAME']."</td> ";
    echo "<td><input type='text' value='' name='email'>".$row['EMAIL']."</td>";
    echo "<td><input type='text' value='' name='mobile_num'>".$row['MOBILE_NUM']."     </td>";
    echo "<td><input type='text' value='' name='remarks'>".$row['REMARKS']."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$row['REQ_DATE']."</td>\n";
echo "</tr>\n";
```

please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe I'm looking at it to easy, but why not change

```
$stid = oci_parse($conn, 'select * from FEEDBACK');
```

to

```
$stid = oci_parse($conn, 'select * from FEEDBACK ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1');
```

It selects the rows in a reversed order, and will only return one row (with the highest ID).

Comment: yah i tried with your query but it is getting error:::Warning: oci_execute() [function.oci-execute]: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended in C:\PORTAL\xampp\htdocs\form_req\form\insert.php on line 31,

Comment: and my intention is to fetch last inserted record through sequence number, so that i can apply for multiple users, thanks for ,please provide me.

Comment: here in my query $stid = oci_parse($conn, 'select * from FEEDBACK where id=:sequence number');               this sequence number i want

Comment: What's the difference between 'the last sequence number' and the 'last inserted id' ??

Comment: There is no difference between last seq num and last inserted id.just i want to fetch inserted record in a form.

Comment: yes now i got it by changing the query to                         select * from FEEDBACK where rownum = 1 order by id desc;                thanks for help and support

Comment: If the answer helps you, please don't forget to mark it as solution (v-mark) on the left of it.